# Let $x \sim N(0,1)$. Find $E[(x+2)^2]$

Tags: statistics

> Let $x \sim N(0,1)$. Find 
>    $$1. E[(x+2)^2]$$
>   $$2. E(x^3)$$

For #1, I know that you can write it as : $E(x^2 +4x +4)$ but can I say  $$E(x^2 +4x +1) = E(x^2) +E(4x) +4 ?$$  I am having doubt because $x^2$ and $4x$ are not independent.

For #2,

I have no clue, I might need moment generating function? But I am not sure how to do it...

Comment: Yes, expectation is linear. $E[X+Y]=E[X]+E[Y]$ even if $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.

Comment: @angryavian Thanks. Do you know when is the case that you can't separate X and Y when they are dependent? Is it the variance?

Comment: In general, $E[XY] \ne E[X] E[Y]$ and $Var(X+Y) \ne Var(X)+Var(Y)$. But both these inequalities become equalities if $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: You can separate variance as long as you include covariance.

Comment: To clarify the comment by A.S., $Var(X+Y) = Var(X) + Var(Y) + 2 Cov(X,Y)$ always, but if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $Cov(X,Y)=0$.

Comment: @angryavian Thank you! That's very helpful!

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Properties

Comment: $E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)$ also holds if $X$ and $Y$ are mean independent (which implies uncorrelated), that is $E(Y|X)=E(Y)$.

Comment: For #2, one way to compute it is to just write out the integral and use integration by parts. However if you are clever, you avoid all that work by noting that $X^3$ is symmetric, so...

Comment: @angryavian yes! so its 0.